# Two differents projects in eclipse: (JPA & EJB) in a EAR Project (problems with CDI)

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jboss, ejb

Hy guys, first: My english is not good, but.. come on:

I have two projects in eclipse:

JPA (with models & dao's)
EJB (with my web services)

and an EAR Project (JPA + EJB). My setup: JBoss 7.1 AS

My problem:

```
@Stateless
@WebService --> THIS IS IN EBJ PROJECT
public class PessoaFisicaWS implements Service {

    @EJB
    private PessoaFisicaDAO dao;

}
```

this is my DAO Impl

```
@Stateless ->> THIS IS IN MY JPA PROJECT
public class JPAPessoaFisicaDAO extends JPAAbstractDAO<PessoaFisicaBean>
        implements PessoaFisicaDAO {

    public PessoaFisicaBean getPessoaFisicaByCPF(String cpf) {
        TypedQuery<PessoaFisicaBean> query = manager.createQuery(
                "SELECT p from PessoaFisicaBean p where p.cpf = :cpf",
                PessoaFisicaBean.class);
        query.setParameter("cpf", cpf);

        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
// with others impl
}
```

OK

**EJB Project** add **JPA Project** in your classpath. OK

NO ERRORS. BUT in deploy:

> > Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'br.com.processo.dao.PessoaFisicaDAO' for binding pacote.PessoaFisicaWS/dao

any idea?

**EDIT**:

When i add (DAO's and your impl) in my EJB Project (same package of WebService) ITS WORKS.
But i need separate in two projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this annotation `@EJB` from `dao` because this is not an EJB.

Comment: i add anotation @Stateless to public class JPAPessoaFisicaDAO | i edit my first post

Comment: it isn't relate to the exception in your question, but this annotation should be also removed. Create a class and put this annotation there, then register EJBs in `ejb-jar.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Each module has its own classloader, so that the visibility of the class is limited to each module. You need create a jar with the interfaces and put in the `lib` directory of the EAR. See more in [*Class Loading in AS7*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsJwG.png), e.g.:

You need create a standard java project for store the business interfaces. The deployment assembly:

[image]

In the project explorere view you see:

[image]

Comment: Hi paul.. thanks for your response. But this is an webservice. PS -> i edit my first post..

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. The error is telling you to reference the Interface not the Implementation.

So make sure that "PessoaFisicaDAO" is an Interface with the @Remote or @LocalBean annotation

```
@EJB
private PessoaFisicaDAO dao;
```